# DB2 Left Outer JOin returning error

Tags: db2

I am new to DB2 and learning.

We have below query trying join table ,but it is returing me an error, can someone please help?

```
SELECT "Q.WRITETIME", "Q.Queue_Name", "Q.Current_Depth", "S.Oldest_Message_Age", "Q.Percent_Full", "Q.Messages_Read_per_Second", "Q.Messages_Put_per_Second", "Q.Maximum_Depth" 
FROM "ITMUSER"."Queue_Long_Term_History" Q
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "ITMUSER"."Queue_Status" S 
           ON 
"Q.Queue_Name" = "S.Queue_Name" 
where "Queue_Name"='PHX.IIB.WAS.DATAREQ.QL'
ORDER BY Q."WRITETIME";
```

Can someone please help me with this query?

I am below error codes when playing:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, 
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,

Answer (score 1):

You've got an invalid column name somewhere...

Do you really need quoted names?

DB2 by default is not case sensitive for schemas, tables or column names.
`mycolumn` is the same as `MYCOLUMN`

If you really need quoted names, then be aware that it has to be an exact match.
`"MyColumn"` is **NOT the same** as `"Mycolumn"`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be issues with your quoting. Each object needs to be quoted separately:     `"SCHEMA"."TABLE"."COLUMN"`

Here's the revised query, which was also missing a table qualifier in the `WHERE` clause. Also, as <kbd>Charles</kbd> mentioned, quoted identifiers are case-sensitive.

```
SELECT "Q"."WRITETIME", "Q"."Queue_Name", "Q"."Current_Depth",
 "S"."Oldest_Message_Age", "Q"."Percent_Full",
 "Q"."Messages_Read_per_Second",
 "Q"."Messages_Put_per_Second", "Q"."Maximum_Depth" 
FROM "ITMUSER"."Queue_Long_Term_History" Q
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "ITMUSER"."Queue_Status" S 
  ON "Q"."Queue_Name" = "S"."Queue_Name" 
WHERE "Q"."Queue_Name"='PHX.IIB.WAS.DATAREQ.QL'
ORDER BY "Q"."WRITETIME"
```